# Shortening a repetitive SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a better way to write the following code, maybe some sort of a loop, etc. I have a temp table created in the query prior to this.  And then I am trying to create different columns, which give me actions that happened on a customer's account in one line, in chronological order.

```
SELECT 
    a.*,
    Action_1 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '1' )),
    Action_1_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '1' )),
    Action_2 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '2' )),
    Action_2_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '2' )),
    Action_3 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '3' )),
    Action_3_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '3' )),
    Action_4 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '4' )),
    Action_4_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '4' )),
    Action_5 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '5' )),
    Action_5_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '5' )),
    Action_6 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '6' )),
    Action_6_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '6' )),
    Action_7 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '7' )),
    Action_7_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '7' )),
    Action_8 = (SELECT Rating_Changed_To FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '8' )),
    Action_8_Time = (SELECT Change_Date FROM #TempICHist WHERE (IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '8' ))
FROM
    #TempICs a
ORDER BY
    a.Programme,a.IC_Created_Date
```

I hope the question is clear, but If there is confusion, i can reply.

Comment: Is `Rank` really a string? If it is an `int` then what do you keep comparing it to a string, i.e. `Rank = '7'` rather than `Rank = 7`?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `apply` with *conditional* aggregation :

```
select a.*, Act_1.*
from #tempics a outer apply
     ( SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN RANK = 1 THEN Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_1,
              MAX(CASE WHEN RANK = 2 THEN Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_2,
              . . . 
              MAX(CASE WHEN RANK = 1 THEN Change_Date END) AS Action_1_Time,
              MAX(CASE WHEN RANK = 2 THEN Change_Date END) AS Action_2_Time,
              . . . 
       FROM #TempICHist 
       WHERE IC_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
     ) Act_1;
```

Comment: This doesnt work, coz it only returns one extra column. The idea is to get those 8 columns back but looking for a way get away with that repetition, sort of like a for loop

Comment: @AmritSingh. . . Check my edited & fill the missing rank.

Answer (score 0):

For each ID you need to project 8 records into 16 different attributes, so your sql will no become much more compact.

However, instead of correlated subqueries you could use left joins, which *might* improve the performance. However, check the explain plans of your rdbms for both queries (which tells you the primitives that the optimizer turns your query into).

```
   SELECT a.*,
          h1.Rating_Changed_To   Action_1,
          h2.Rating_Changed_To   Action_2,
          h3.Rating_Changed_To   Action_3,
          h4.Rating_Changed_To   Action_4,
          h5.Rating_Changed_To   Action_5,
          h6.Rating_Changed_To   Action_6,
          h7.Rating_Changed_To   Action_7,
          h8.Rating_Changed_To   Action_8,
          h1.Change_Date         Action_1_Time,
          h2.Change_Date         Action_2_Time,
          h3.Change_Date         Action_3_Time,
          h4.Change_Date         Action_4_Time,
          h5.Change_Date         Action_5_Time,
          h6.Change_Date         Action_6_Time,
          h7.Change_Date         Action_7_Time,
          h8.Change_Date         Action_8_Time,
     FROM #TempICs a
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h1 ON ( h1.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '1' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h2 ON ( h2.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '2' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h3 ON ( h3.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '3' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h4 ON ( h4.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '4' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h5 ON ( h5.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '5' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h6 ON ( h6.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '6' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h7 ON ( h7.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '7' ) 
LEFT JOIN #TempICHist h8 ON ( h8.C_ID_18 = a.ICID_18 AND Rank = '8' ) 
 ORDER BY a.Programme,a.IC_Created_Date
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can condense the data using aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 1 THEN ih.Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 1 THEN ih.Change_Date END) AS Action_1_Time,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 2 THEN ih.Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 2 THEN ih.Change_Date END) AS Action_2_Time,
          . . . 
FROM #TempICHist ih
GROUP BY ih.IC_ID_18;
```

You can then join this in:

```
SELECT i.*,
       ih.Action_1, ih.Action_1_Time, . . . 
FROM #TempICs i LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 1 THEN ih.Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_1,
             MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 1 THEN ih.Change_Date END) AS Action_1_Time,
             MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 2 THEN ih.Rating_Changed_To END) AS Action_2,
             MAX(CASE WHEN ih.RANK = 2 THEN ih.Change_Date END) AS Action_2_Time,
              . . . 
      FROM #TempICHist ih
      GROUP BY ih.IC_ID_18
     ) ih
     ON ih.C_ID_18 = i.ICID_18
ORDER BY i.Programme, i.IC_Created_Date;
```

When learning to write queries, it is a very good habit to learn to use meaningful table aliases (abbreviations for table names) and to qualify *all* column references so it is clear what table they come from.